# Best fit square to quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, shapes, physics-engine

I've got a shape consisting of four points, A, B, C and D, of which the only their position is known. The goal is to transform these points to have specific angles and offsets relative to each other.

For example: `A(-1,-1) B(2,-1) C(1,1) D(-2,1)`, which should be transformed to a perfect square (all angles 90) with offsets between AB, BC, CD and AD all being 2. The result should be a square slightly rotated counter-clockwise.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?
I'm using this for a simple block simulation program.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to give a clear answer to your question.  For example, if you were to move B to (1,-1) and D to (-1,1) you would have a square (though not rotated away from the coordinate axes).  Are you, perhaps, looking for the square which minimises the distances you have to translate your 4 points to make a square ?

Comment: I suggest retitling this "Best fit square to quadrilateral", so that others will find it easier in search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark alluded, we can use constrained optimization to find the side 2 square that minimizes the square of the distance to the corners of the original.

We need to minimize `f = (a-A)^2 + (b-B)^2 + (c-C)^2 + (d-D)^2` (where the square is actually a dot product of the vector argument with itself) subject to some constraints.

Following the method of [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), I chose the following distance constraints:

```
g1 = (a-b)^2 - 4
g2 = (c-b)^2 - 4
g3 = (d-c)^2 - 4
```

and the following angle constraints:

```
g4 = (b-a).(c-b)
g5 = (c-b).(d-c)
```

A quick napkin sketch should convince you that these constraints are sufficient.

We then want to minimize f subject to the g's all being zero.

The Lagrange function is:

L = f + Sum(i = 1 to 5, li gi)

where the `li`s are the Lagrange multipliers.

The gradient is non-linear, so we have to take a hessian and use [multivariate Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization#Higher_dimensions) to iterate to a solution.

Here's the solution I got (red) for the data given (black):

[image: Best fit square]

This took 5 iterations, after which the L2 norm of the step was 6.5106e-9.

Comment: +1: I just can't be bothered to write such good answers, you're a credit to the SO community.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Accepted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

While Codie CodeMonkey's solution is a perfectly valid one (and a great use case for the Lagrangian Multipliers at that), I believe that it's worth mentioning that if the **side length is not given** this particular problem actually has a **closed form solution**.

We would like to minimise the distance between the corners of our fitted square and the ones of the given quadrilateral. This is equivalent to minimising the cost function:

```
f(x1,...,y4) = (x1-ax)^2+(y1-ay)^2 + (x2-bx)^2+(y2-by)^2 +
                (x3-cx)^2+(y3-cy)^2 + (x4-dx)^2+(y4-dy)^2
```

Where `Pi = (xi,yi)` are the corners of the fitted square and `A = (ax,ay)` through `D = (dx,dy)` represent the given corners of the quadrilateral **in clockwise order**. Since we are fitting a square we have certain contraints regarding the positions of the four corners. Actually, if two opposite corners are given, they are enough to describe a unique square (save for the mirror image on the diagonal).

[Parametrization of the points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQmhb.png)

This means that two opposite corners are enough to represent our target square. We can parametrise the two remaining corners using the components of the first two. In the above example we express `P2` and `P4` in terms of `P1 = (x1,y1)` and `P3 = (x3,y3)`. If you need a visualisation of the geometrical intuition behind the parametrisation of a square you can play [with the interactive version](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l1uhrparfu).

```
P2 = (x2,y2) = ( (x1+x3-y3+y1)/2 , (y1+y3-x1+x3)/2 )
P4 = (x4,y4) = ( (x1+x3+y3-y1)/2 , (y1+y3+x1-x3)/2 )
```

Substituting for `x2,x4,y2,y4` means that `f(x1,...,y4)` can be rewritten to:

```
f(x1,x3,y1,y3) = (x1-ax)^2+(y1-ay)^2 + ((x1+x3-y3+y1)/2-bx)^2+((y1+y3-x1+x3)/2-by)^2 + 
                (x3-cx)^2+(y3-cy)^2 + ((x1+x3+y3-y1)/2-dx)^2+((y1+y3+x1-x3)/2-dy)^2
```

a function which only depends on `x1,x3,y1,y3`. To find the minimum of the resulting function we then set the partial derivatives of `f(x1,x3,y1,y3)` equal to zero. They are the following:

```
df/dx1 = 4x1-dy-dx+by-bx-2ax = 0   -->   x1 = ( dy+dx-by+bx+2ax)/4
df/dx3 = 4x3+dy-dx-by-bx-2cx = 0   -->   x3 = (-dy+dx+by+bx+2cx)/4
df/dy1 = 4y1-dy+dx-by-bx-2ay = 0   -->   y1 = ( dy-dx+by+bx+2ay)/4
df/dy3 = 4y3-dy-dx-2cy-by+bx = 0   -->   y3 = ( dy+dx+by-bx+2cy)/4
```

You may see where this is going, as simple rearrangment of the terms leads to the final solution.

[Final solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIaIB.png)